# How can we integrate a custom framework into my own framework. So that i will give only my framework to the users

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I have a third party framework, and i am creating a seperate a framework and i dont want to  expose the third party framework to the users.

Suppose i have a framework called A and I have created a framework named B. I am using the A framework in my custom framework named B. I would want to give my custom framework to the users and there wont be have any kind of access to the framework A.

Can we integrate a custom framework into one another. Please help me guys

Comment: Make sure you've cleared this with the client.  This could pose significant legal issues.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the source code, integrate the source code. If not, do "man dyld", read the explanation of @executable_path, @loader_path and @rpath to learn how to create a framework which uses another framework - the user still needs both frameworks.

And as sapi said, make sure that everything is legally fine.